# C struct pointer iteration

Tags: c, memory, pointers, struct, iteration

I did not expect to be able to increment a pointer to a struct in a memory block of structs.  But it seems to work.  Is there any case where this does not work?  If I create a "list" of structs then I should always be able to increment the pointer to them and C will figure out how many bytes to move by?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct User {
    int id;
    char name[32];
    float net_worth;
};
typedef struct User User;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    User* u1 = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User));
    u1->id = 1;
    strcpy(u1->name, "Mike");
    u1->net_worth = 43.45;
    User* u2 = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User));
    u2->id = 2;
    strcpy(u2->name, "Pablo");
    u2->net_worth = -2.00;
    User* u3 = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User));
    u3->id = 3;
    strcpy(u3->name, "Frederick");
    u3->net_worth = 7329213.45;

    User** users = (User**)malloc(sizeof(User)*10);
    *users = u1;
    printf("%s\n", ((User*)(*users))->name);
    *users++;
    *users = u2;
    printf("%s\n", ((User*)(*users))->name);
    *users++;
    *users = u3;
    printf("%s\n", ((User*)(*users))->name);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question, you see that it works right?

Comment: Yea I just want to make sure I am not missing anything and I understand it.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the expression `*users++`? The '*' is superfluous (it just dereferences the result of `++`). It's also confusing as it may seem that you are attempting to increment `*users`, rather than `users` itself.

Comment: I was actually going to point that out, users++ will suffice.

Comment: The cast `((User*)(*users))` is also superfluous. `users` is a `User**`; therefore `(*users)` is already a `User*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very much by design. Assume you have

```
User userArray[16];
```

You could either access the second user via `userArray[1]`, or `*(userArray + 1)`, or get a pointer to the first element and increment it via `++`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply: yes. This is why pointers have type.

Comment: I couldnt post a comment with word yes as it required 15 chars

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how it's meant to work. Adding 1 to a pointer within an array will actually advance to the next element (C will adjust the memory address by the correct amount, the size of the structure).

The only time this won't work is when you go too far. A pointer is only valid (for dereferencing and pointer arithmetic) if it points to within the array or (for arithmetic only) one beyond. So:

```
int x[10];
int *px = &(x[9]);  // Points to last element, okay to dereference.
px++;               // Points one beyond, still okay for aritmetic.
px++;               // Don't use this for anything.
```

is considered undefined behaviour if you try to use the pointer afterwards.

Comment: Just a FIY: it's ok to have a pointer pointing one beyond the end (and use that pointer for pointer arithmetic), but it's not ok to dereference it.

Comment: Second FIY: You would probably write x + 9 instead of &(x[9]) (x also has type int*).

Comment: @jforberg, seasoned code monkeys like us may realise there's no difference but I've found from teaching experience that beginners more readily understand "the address of element number 9" than "adding 9 to the array".

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

<sub>(text to fill the 30 chars post requirement)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> and C will figure out how many bytes to move by?

Yes. That is why C imposes the limits that it does on what you can put in a struct: every instance of a struct of a given type has to be the same size, and the compiler must be able to figure out that size at compile-time, for this scheme to work.